# Why does time spontaneously change in debian?

Tags: linux, debian, date

Debian 8.
Host system, no virtualization.
Time synchronization systems are disabled. ntp, rdate, sdwdate are not installed.

```
# timedatectl
Local time: Thu 2019-08-22 14:02:05 +03
Universal time: Thu 2019-08-22 11:02:05 UTC
RTC time: Thu 2019-08-22 11:00:10
Time zone: Europe/Minsk (+03, +0300)
NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
RTC in local TZ: no
DST active: n/a
```

A second after setting the time, it changes by several minutes.

Examples:

```
# ntpdate 0.ru.pool.ntp.org  && date && sleep 1 && date
22 Aug 14:02:28 ntpdate[31388]: step time server 195.211.77.68 offset -115.009072 sec
Thu Aug 22 14:02:28 +03 2019
Thu Aug 22 14:04:24 +03 2019

# hwclock --hctosys && date && sleep 1 && date
Thu Aug 22 14:01:51 +03 2019
Thu Aug 22 14:03:46 +03 2019

# date -s "2019-08-22 14:04:53" && date && sleep 1 && date
Thu Aug 22 14:04:53 +03 2019
Thu Aug 22 14:04:53 +03 2019
Thu Aug 22 14:06:49 +03 2019
```

When changing manually, messages appear in the logs

```
Aug 22 16:30:50 wisi systemd[1200]: Time has been changed
Aug 22 16:30:50 wisi systemd[1]: Time has been changed
Aug 22 16:32:45 wisi systemd[1200]: Time has been changed
Aug 22 16:32:45 wisi systemd[1]: Time has been changed
```

here the first two lines are about manual time change, the second two are about the fact that the system “adjusted” the time back.

```
# ps afx | grep [1]200
 1200 ?        Ss     0:06 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

Attempts to disable *timers.target, time-sync.target, systemd-timesyncd* have no effect.

In the tcpdump logs, it can be seen that there are no requests on the 123rd port when "adjusting".
The time of "adjustment" is not constant and changes, it was observed from 1 to 5 minutes.

What caused it and how to get rid of it?

**UPD1:**
@Seth,

> Seeing timedatectl after the change would be interesting.

```
# timedatectl && ntpdate 0.ru.pool.ntp.org  && timedatectl && sleep 1 && timedatectl
      Local time: Fri 2019-08-23 14:10:57 +03
  Universal time: Fri 2019-08-23 11:10:57 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2019-08-23 11:09:19
       Time zone: Europe/Minsk (+03, +0300)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
23 Aug 14:09:25 ntpdate[19282]: step time server 192.36.143.130 offset -98.695079 sec
      Local time: Fri 2019-08-23 14:09:25 +03
  Universal time: Fri 2019-08-23 11:09:25 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2019-08-23 11:09:26
       Time zone: Europe/Minsk (+03, +0300)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
      Local time: Fri 2019-08-23 14:11:05 +03
  Universal time: Fri 2019-08-23 11:11:05 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2019-08-23 11:09:27
       Time zone: Europe/Minsk (+03, +0300)
     NTP enabled: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

> What do you mean they have no effect? Did you verify whenever it is a
>   correct adjustment or not?

Yes, of course, the problem started when the default service is enabled.
For the test, I tried to stop them, but this does not affect the result.

**UPD2**

As a test, I disconnected all network cables. Everything is as before.
But any "network" assumptions can now be excluded.

Comment: Seeing `timedatectl` after the change would be interesting. What do you mean they have no effect? Did you verify whenever it is a correct adjustment or not?

Comment: are you sure you're syncing with same server?

Comment: @cjayho, this is the host system, that is, there is no synchronization from virtualization systems. As far as I can tell, there is no synchronization with third-party servers (tcpdump testifies to this).

Comment: Yes but you should edit the question. It's content relevant to it. Answers are ... answers to your question. What default service are you talking about? [the man pages](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/systemd/timedatectl.1.en.html) would suggest that you still might have a different service doing time sync. Your verification using tcpdump should at least show your explicit calls. If you only watched for external connections also watch for intranet connections (depending on your setup) as e.g. your router or another machine might be a NTP source.

Comment: @Seth, there are no ntp servers on the intranet, but I still checked tcpdump on all interfaces, no ntp requests were observed at the time the time was "adjusted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oskam returns the time to the previously set.

https://github.com/gfto/oscam/blob/2780c48789c8e1427df4078ea9b06e0b51594bbc/oscam-time.c

```
#if defined(CLOCKFIX)
    if (tv.tv_sec > lasttime.tv_sec || (tv.tv_sec == lasttime.tv_sec && tv.tv_usec >= lasttime.tv_usec)){ // check for time issues!
        lasttime = tv; // register this valid time 
    }
    else
    {
        tv = lasttime;
        settimeofday(&tv, NULL); // set time back to last known valid time
        //fprintf(stderr, "*** WARNING: BAD TIME AFFECTING WHOLE OSCAM ECM HANDLING, SYSTEMTIME SET TO LAST KNOWN VALID TIME **** \n");
    }
```